# Unable to enter data in mongo database in express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

```
router.get('/wiki/:topicname', function(req, res, next) {
    var topicname = req.params.topicname;
    console.log(topicname);




    summary.wikitext(topicname, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }
            if (!result) {
                return res.send('No article found');
            }
            $ = cheerio.load(result);

            var db = req.db;
            var collection = db.get('try1');
            collection.insert({ "topicname" : topicname, "content": result }, function (err, doc){
                if (err) {
                    // If it failed, return error
                    res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
                }
                else {
                    // And forward to success page
                    res.send("Added succesfully");
                }
            });

      });
```

Using this code, I am trying to add the fetched content from Wikipedia in to the collection `try1`. The message **"Added succesfully"** is displayed. But the collection seems to be empty. The data is not inserted in the database

Comment: What happens when you `console.log` the doc from the insert?

Comment: It shows the contents properly

Comment: In the callback inside the `collection.insert`, check for the existance of the `doc`

`if(doc) {
    console.log("DOC : " + JSON.stringify(doc));
}`

Comment: How are you checking the content, whether it is empty or not? Are you using Mongo shell or some other tool like RoboMongo?

Comment: If `console.log`'ing the doc on the insert,it should be there. Are you using the correct syntax to find the correct document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your mongod server in a correct path,i.e, same path as that of what you are using to check the contents of collection.

`sudo mongod --dbpath <actual-path>`

Comment: Thank you so much. My mongod server was running in different directory.

Answer (score 1):

The data must be there, mongodb has { w: 1, j: true } write concern options by default so its only returns without an error if the document is truly inserted if there were any document to insert.

Things you should consider:

-Do NOT use insert function, its depricated use insertOne, insertMany or bulkWrite. ref.: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#insert

-The insert methods callback has two parameters. Error if there was an error, and result. The result object has several properties with could be used for after insert result testing like: result.insertedCount will return the number of inserted documents.

So according to these in your code you only test for error but you can insert zero documents without an error.

Also its not clear to me where do you get your database name from. Is the following correct in your code? Are you sure you are connected to the database you want to use?

```
var db = req.db;
```

Also you don't have to enclose your property names with " in your insert method. The insert should look something like this:

```
col.insertOne({topicname : topicname, content: result}, function(err, r) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(r.insertedCount);
    }
});
```